# Error Compiling Tensorflow From Source - No module named 'keras_applications'

Tags: python, tensorflow, compilation, bazel

I am attempting to build tensorflow from source with MKL optimizations on an Intel CPU setup. I have followed the official instructions [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources) up until the command `bazel build --config=mkl --config=opt //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package`.

Unfortunately, the compilation runs for some period of time and then fails. I'd appreciate any help with this matter.

**Updated Output log** (using bazel --verbose_failures):

```
   ERROR: /home/jok/build/tensorflow/tensorflow/BUILD:584:1: Executing genrule //tensorflow:tensorflow_python_api_gen failed (Exit 1): bash failed: error executing command 
  (cd /home/jok/.cache/bazel/_bazel_jok120/737f8d6dbadde71050b1e0783c31ea62/execroot/org_tensorflow && \
  exec env - \
    LD_LIBRARY_PATH=LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/cuda-9.0/lib64/:/usr/local/cuda-9.0/extras/CUPTI/lib64 \
    PATH=/home/jok/.conda/envs/tf_mkl/bin:/home/jok/bin:/opt/anaconda3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/snap/bin:/home/jok/bin \
  /bin/bash -c 'source external/bazel_tools/tools/genrule/genrule-setup.sh; bazel-out/host/bin/tensorflow/create_tensorflow.python_api --root_init_template=tensorflow/api_template.__init__.py --apidir=bazel-out/host/genfiles/tensorflow --apiname=tensorflow --apiversion=1 --package=tensorflow.python --output_package=tensorflow bazel-out/host/genfiles/tensorflow/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/tensorflow/app/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/tensorflow/bitwise/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/tensorflow/compat/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/tensorflow/data/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/tensorflow/debugging/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/tensorflow/distributions/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/tensorflow/dtypes/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/tensorflow/errors/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/tensorflow/feature_column/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/tensorflow/gfile/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/tensorflow/graph_util/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/tensorflow/image/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/tensorflow/io/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/tensorflow/initializers/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/tensorflow/keras/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/tensorflow/keras/activations/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/tensorflow/keras/applications/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/tensorflow/keras/applications/densenet/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/tensorflow/keras/applications/inception_resnet_v2/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/tensorflow/keras/applications/inception_v3/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/tensorflow/keras/applications/mobilenet/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/tensorflow/keras/applications/mobilenet_v2/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/tensorflow/keras/applications/nasnet/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/tensorflow/keras/applications/resnet50/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/tensorflow/keras/applications/vgg16/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/tensorflow/keras/applications/vgg19/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/tensorflow/keras/applications/xception/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/tensorflow/keras/backend/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/tensorflow/keras/callbacks/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/tensorflow/keras/constraints/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/tensorflow/keras/datasets/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/tensorflow/keras/datasets/boston_housing/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/tensorflow/keras/datasets/cifar10/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/tensorflow/keras/datasets/cifar100/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/tensorflow/keras/datasets/fashion_mnist/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/tensorflow/keras/datasets/imdb/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/tensorflow/keras/datasets/mnist/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/tensorflow/keras/datasets/reuters/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/tensorflow/keras/estimator/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/tensorflow/keras/initializers/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/tensorflow/keras/layers/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/tensorflow/keras/losses/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/tensorflow/keras/metrics/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/tensorflow/keras/models/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/tensorflow/keras/optimizers/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/tensorflow/keras/preprocessing/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/tensorflow/keras/preprocessing/image/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/tensorflow/keras/preprocessing/sequence/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/tensorflow/keras/preprocessing/text/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/tensorflow/keras/regularizers/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/tensorflow/keras/utils/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/tensorflow/keras/wrappers/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/tensorflow/keras/wrappers/scikit_learn/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/tensorflow/layers/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/tensorflow/linalg/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/tensorflow/logging/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/tensorflow/losses/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/tensorflow/manip/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/tensorflow/math/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/tensorflow/metrics/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/tensorflow/nn/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/tensorflow/nn/rnn_cell/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/tensorflow/profiler/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/tensorflow/python_io/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/tensorflow/quantization/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/tensorflow/resource_loader/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/tensorflow/strings/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/tensorflow/saved_model/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/tensorflow/saved_model/builder/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/tensorflow/saved_model/constants/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/tensorflow/saved_model/loader/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/tensorflow/saved_model/main_op/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/tensorflow/saved_model/signature_constants/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/tensorflow/saved_model/signature_def_utils/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/tensorflow/saved_model/tag_constants/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/tensorflow/saved_model/utils/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/tensorflow/sets/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/tensorflow/sparse/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/tensorflow/spectral/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/tensorflow/summary/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/tensorflow/sysconfig/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/tensorflow/test/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/tensorflow/train/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/tensorflow/train/queue_runner/__init__.py bazel-out/host/genfiles/tensorflow/user_ops/__init__.py')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jok/.cache/bazel/_bazel_jok120/737f8d6dbadde71050b1e0783c31ea62/execroot/org_tensorflow/bazel-out/host/bin/tensorflow/create_tensorflow.python_api.runfiles/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/python/tools/api/generator/create_python_api.py", line 27, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.tools.api.generator import doc_srcs
  File "/home/jok/.cache/bazel/_bazel_jok120/737f8d6dbadde71050b1e0783c31ea62/execroot/org_tensorflow/bazel-out/host/bin/tensorflow/create_tensorflow.python_api.runfiles/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 81, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import keras
  File "/home/jok/.cache/bazel/_bazel_jok120/737f8d6dbadde71050b1e0783c31ea62/execroot/org_tensorflow/bazel-out/host/bin/tensorflow/create_tensorflow.python_api.runfiles/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/python/keras/__init__.py", line 25, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.keras import applications
  File "/home/jok/.cache/bazel/_bazel_jok120/737f8d6dbadde71050b1e0783c31ea62/execroot/org_tensorflow/bazel-out/host/bin/tensorflow/create_tensorflow.python_api.runfiles/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/python/keras/applications/__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    import keras_applications
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keras_applications'
Target //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package failed to build
INFO: Elapsed time: 695.098s, Critical Path: 152.03s
INFO: 7029 processes: 7029 local.
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully
```

Comment: I assume you ran the ./configure command? Also can you please rerun your build command with the --verbose_failures flag set and update your output.

Comment: @geekonedge Yes, I did run `./configure`. I updated the output while adding verbose_failures to my build command. Thanks for offering to help me out.

Answer (score 17):

This appears to be a problem with Tensorflow 1.10 build. I recommend you check out the r1.9 branch as it builds totally fine. Either the dependency list needs to be updated or Tensorflow will fix this. If you are determined to run the r.1.10 api then run the following in terminal:

```
pip install keras_applications==1.0.4 --no-deps
pip install keras_preprocessing==1.0.2 --no-deps
pip install h5py==2.8.0
```

Comment: Yes, your suggested fixes worked for the 1.10 version. I did not try using an older release. Thank you! In the future, I’ll make sure to check out recent open issues on the repository.

Comment: Great. Thanks for confirming!

Answer (score 0):

If you're just interested in the release version (`git tag` will show you all available releases), run `git checkout v1.10.1`  before the `./configure` step. Then you can follow the official instructions without installing additional dependencies.

Currently, a master branch build will give me the following error in Keras code that worked previously (this is after calling `model.fit_generator()` from the stand alone version of Keras):

```
`steps_per_epoch=None` is only valid for a generator based on the `keras.utils.Sequence` class. Please specify `steps_per_epoch` or use the `keras.utils.Sequence` class.
```

Builds based on the 1.10.1 release version of TensorFlow don't cause this error.