# How to debug Tensorflow segmentation fault in model.fit()?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to run the [Keras MINST example](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/examples/mnist_cnn.py) using tensorflow-gpu with a Geforce 2080. My environment is Anaconda on a Linux system.

I am running the unmodified example from a command line python session. I get the following output:

```
Using TensorFlow backend.
Device mapping:
/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 -> device: 0, name: GeForce RTX 2080, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 7.5
x_train shape: (60000, 28, 28, 1)
60000 train samples
10000 test samples
Train on 60000 samples, validate on 10000 samples
Epoch 1/12
conv2d_1/random_uniform/RandomUniform: (RandomUniform): 
/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
conv2d_1/random_uniform/sub: (Sub): 
/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
conv2d_1/random_uniform/mul: (Mul): 
/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
conv2d_1/random_uniform: (Add): 
/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
[...]
```

The last lines I receive are:

```
training/Adadelta/Const_31: (Const): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
training/Adadelta/mul_46/x: (Const): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
training/Adadelta/mul_47/x: (Const): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

From reading around I assumed this might be a memory problem and added these lines to prevent the GPU from running out of memory:

```
config = tf.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=True)
config.gpu_options.per_process_gpu_memory_fraction=0.3
K.tensorflow_backend.set_session(tf.Session(config=config))
```

Checking with the `nvidia-smi` tool that the GPU is actually used (`watch -n1 nvidia-smi`)I can confirm from the following output (in this run no `per_process_gpu_memory_fraction` was set to 1):

[image]

I suspect a version incompatibility somewhere between CUDA, Keras and Tensorflow to be the issue, but I don't know, how to debug this.

What debugging measures are available to get to the bottom of this? What other issues might be the reason for this segfault?

EDIT: I experimented further and replacing the model with this code works fine:

```
model = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=input_shape),
    keras.layers.Dense(128, activation=tf.nn.relu),
    keras.layers.Dense(10, activation=tf.nn.softmax)
])
```

However once I introduce a convolution layer like so

```
model = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=input_shape),
#    keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=input_shape),
    keras.layers.Flatten(),
    keras.layers.Dense(128, activation=tf.nn.relu),
    keras.layers.Dense(10, activation=tf.nn.softmax)
```

])

then I again get the aforementioned segfault.

All packets have been installed through Anaconda. I have installed

- conda 4.5.11
- python 3.6.6
- keras-gpu 2.2.4
- tensorflow 1.12.0
- tensorflow-gpu 1.12.0
- cudnn 7.2.1
- cudatoolkit 9.2

EDIT: I tried the same code in a non anaconda environment and it works flawlessly. I would prefer to use anaconda though to avoid system updates breaking things.

Comment: Your model parameter numbers & batch number?

Comment: Just for testing try to run your code with batchsize=1

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The model parameters are the unmodified parameters from the example in the link. I just tried with batchsize = 1 and ran into the same problem.

Comment: ok back to the bases, your model is pretty small. You should not have memory problems at all. How did you install tensorflow-gpu, in which environment i.e. anaconda or from source , python version etc.

Comment: I installed and run everything through Anaconda. I edited my question to show the versions.

Comment: uninstall tensorflow (keep tensorflow-gpu)

Comment: It may be wiser uninstall both and reinstall tensorflow-gpu

Comment: btw I'm using the same environment with gtx980 but with cuda9.0, because I've had problems with 9.2...

Comment: Conda lists `tensorflow` as a dependency for `tensorflow-gpu`, I don't think it's possible to install only `tensorflow-gpu`.

Comment: It is possible for me it is working fine. You don't need tensorflow Furthermore the preferred way to install tensorflow on conda is via pip install. Read tensorflow documentation.

Comment: I use conda install for most packages, but tensorflow is not such. I guess if you would install it via pip (from anaconda environment terminal) you wouldn't have the issues, though the other problem can be cuda9.2.

Comment: Ok, I have it working for now in my native environment, even though this is not the preferred option. I'll keep the question open, since I still don't know the best approach to debug this issue.
Thanks for you help!

Comment: You can choose the harder way, it is not a problem, if you have to choose that anyway, but it would be a good test if it works that way ensuring that the error 
 doesn't come from your physical memory problem, because the physical(hardware) gpu memory fault causes the same error msg based on several reference I read(though it could be the very last guess and I hope it will not.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Build the tensorflow from source(r1.13) .Conv2D segmentation fault fixed.

follow [Build from Source](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source)

my GPU : RTX 2070
Ubuntu 16.04
Python 3.5.2
Nvidia Driver 410.78
CUDA - 10.0.130
cuDNN-10.0 - 7.4.2.24
TensorRT-5.0.0
Compute Capability: 7.5

Build : tensorflow-1.13.0rc0-cp35-cp35m-linux_x86_64

Download prebuilt  from https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/22706

Answer (score 3):

I had the exact same problem on a very similar system as Francois but using a RTX2070 on which I could reliably reproduce the segmentation fault error when using the conv2d function executed on the GPU. My setting:

- Ubuntu: 18.04
- GPU: RTX 2070
- CUDA: 10
- cudnn: 7
- conda with python 3.6

I finally solved it by ***building tensorflow from source*** into a new conda environment. For a fantastic guide see e.g. the following link:
https://gist.github.com/Brainiarc7/6d6c3f23ea057775b72c52817759b25c

This is basically like any other build-tensorflow-from-source guide and consisted in my case of the following steps:

1. insalling bazel
2. cloning tensorflow from git and running `./configure`
3. running the appropriate `bazel build` command (see link for details)

Some minor issues came up during the build, one of which was solved by installing 3 packages manually, using:

```
pip install keras_applications==1.0.4 --no-deps
pip install keras_preprocessing==1.0.2 --no-deps
pip install h5py==2.8.0
```

which I found out using this answer here:
[Error Compiling Tensorflow From Source - No module named 'keras_applications'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51771039/error-compiling-tensorflow-from-source-no-module-named-keras-applications/51774943#51774943)

conv2d now works like a charm when using the gpu!

However, since all this took a fairly long time (building from source takes over an hour, not counting the search for the solution on the internet) I recommend to make a backup of the system after you get it working, e.g. using timeshift or any other program that you like.

Comment: Please provide context for the links because your answer will become worthless if those links go dead. See the help centers guidelines on answering if you want more detail: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: Thanks for the input @AonghasM, I tried to add some more details to my answer

Answer (score 2):

I had the same Conv2D problem with:

- Ubuntu 18.04
- Graphic card: GeForce RTX 2080
- CUDA: cuda_10.0.130_410
- CUDNN: cudnn-10.0-linux-x64-v7.4.2
- conda with Python 3.6

Best advice was from this link: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/24383

So a fix should come with **Tensorflow 1.13**.
In the meantime, using Tensorflow 1.13 nightly build (Dec 26, 2018) + using tensorflow.keras instead of keras **solved the issue**.