# Does compilation start from beginning or resume after fixing error while building Tensorflow from source?

Tags: tensorflow, bazel, tensorflow2.0

I need to compile Tensorflow from source for compute capability 3.0

I was compiling Tensorflow and I got this error after 6 hours of compiling:

```
cache/bazel/_bazel_maydin/435ff134a8a529ccec16636685173684/execroot/org_tensorflow/bazel-out/host/bin/tensorflow/create_tensorflow.python_api_2_tf_python_api_gen_v2.runfiles/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/python/keras/preprocessing/__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
   import keras_preprocessing
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keras_preprocessing'
Target //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package failed to build
Use --verbose_failures to see the command lines of failed build steps.
INFO: Elapsed time: 20674.165s, Critical Path: 247.43s
INFO: 12297 processes: 12297 local.
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully
```

In below link, I found this answer and I think it will work.
[Error Compiling Tensorflow From Source - No module named 'keras_applications'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51771039/error-compiling-tensorflow-from-source-no-module-named-keras-applications)

```
pip install keras_applications==1.0.4 --no-deps
pip install keras_preprocessing==1.0.2 --no-deps
pip install h5py==2.8.0
```

I also got similar error before beginning of build where it says numpy is missing, i just installed it via pip and build started without problem.

But I am scared to run build command again. Because I don't want to compile everything 6 hours again.

**If I start building again does it start all over from beginning or it continue from where it failed?**

Build command I used is this:
`bazel build --config=opt --config=cuda //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package`

I cloned tensorflow repository, checkout to branch 2.0 and started build.

Additional info about system:

- Cuda 10.0.130
- cuDNN 7.6.2
- Bazel 0.26.1
- Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: You being scared of running the build again after an attempted fix is not a question. Please edit your question with a the results of your attempt. If the fix does indeed solve your problem, then this is a duplicate, otherwise if you encounter a new error, then it might turn into a legit question.

Comment: Question was if I run build again, does it start from beginning or continue from where it failed. I edited question for clarity.

Comment: Now your question has become very confusing; your title and body is about keras packages and your actual question is about resuming a bazel build. I suggest you identify what exactly you want to ask and keep it short and simple for the community to help you out as best as it can.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It resumes compiling where it left off after fixing errors.

Comment: Bazel is incremental. It doesn't re-do the work that has been done, unless you ran `bazel clean` or `bazel clean --expunge`, which is rarely needed.

Comment: It doesn't seem so. bazel is awful

Comment: In my experience, building tensorflow always starts from the beginning again after a build error. Building on Ubuntu 18.4 on Jetson Nano.